# Re-logging in was rejected immediately after logging out of a web site in C#

Tags: c#, session, cookies, logout

I am developing a console application in C# to do some background scraping from a web site. There is no use of webbrowser, winform or ASP etc., just plain http request & response.

I have this problem of logging out the site and the session is still alive so my relogging in is rejected soon after logging out because the site only allows one concurrent user to login. I have done google research and found no clue yet.

Here is the logout code:

```
    public HttpResult logout()
    {
        HttpHelper http = new HttpHelper();
        HttpItem item = new HttpItem()
        {
            URL = "https://w w w.mysite.com/logoff",
            Method = "get",
            ResultCookieType = ResultCookieType.CookieCollection,
            Allowautoredirect = true,
        };
        HttpResult res = http.GetHtml(item);

        return res;
    }
```

I have used Httpwatch to have a peek of the request/response headers as well as the cookies. What I found is that the response contains three cookies with values zeros after logging out. My impression is that in the case of a browser, these cookies gets updated so relogging in request will be redirected to login page. How can I do it like a browser does it?

Comment: You should assign the cookies got from Login request to Logoff request. The easy way is to use the same request instance.

Comment: The main reason I force a logout is that I need to make sure my re-login will not be rejected while I am doing repeat testing of scraping. Once I close down my application, I am not sure where to grab the old cookie as you suggested. The old session usually expire in 5 minutes so I can login again but it is still bothersome.

Comment: I don't know the HttpHelper class, but I suppose that you can get in Login HttpResult the Cookies (CookieCollection or CookiesContainer). You may store the cookies to reuse them in the Logoff Request. I don't think that there is something to do with the cookies got from Logoff request. I rather think that the Logoff failed because the logoff request didn't contained expected cookies.

Comment: Here is the printout from the HttpResult:  STAT%5FUID=6E884BB1-A1CC-4244-A9C5-926AF4CF6B61
STAT%5FUNIQUE%5FUID=8EEDF377-D29D-4AF8-AAE0-3AF4B5358ED4
IV%5FUID=0
IV%5FUID%5FKEY=0
UKL=0
JSESSIONID=a7Ph4Ebj3Jq5

Comment: HttpHelper is just a wrapper class to encapsulate the details of HttpRequest and HttpResponse. The cookies and their values printed out from the HttpResult look exactly  the same as what I see using IE and HttpWatch so logout is partially success except that the new cookies are not written into file as a browser does so the old cookies (still valid) are still there to be used for login. How can I remove the old one and add the new one?

Comment: Now I modified my HttpHelper to write CookieCollection from response object to a file and read it back and assign it to request object before making request. Still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was due to shutdown by TerminateProcess that forced a closedown of of my main app along with the logout before it had a chance to run. 
So I replace TerminateProcess with a soft close which gives signal to the logout to run properly before my main app's close. I also cancel the logout step I used before login. This way, the cookies are invalidated and stored at logout. Now if I try to login right after logout, everything is fine because of the magic in the cookies. One lesson learned is that we need to use CookieCollection in stead of simple cookie when making request. The former will take care of updating cookies in the cookie container.